# How to make React Recharts tooltip modal over all charts?

Tags: reactjs, d3.js, tooltip, bar-chart

I am using React Recharts (http://recharts.org) to draw barcharts with customized tooltips.

```
 <BarChart width={400} height={300} data={data}
        margin={{top: 5, right: 30, left: 10, bottom: 5}}>
          <XAxis dataKey="name"/>
          <YAxis/>
          <CartesianGrid strokeDasharray="3 3"/>
          <Tooltip content={<CustomTooltip/>}/>
          <Legend />
          <Bar dataKey="pv" barSize={20} fill="#8884d8" />
   </BarChart>
```

But my tooltip box is quite big as example below:

http://jsfiddle.net/jiangzhang/zjbbbdtj/11/

I found part of the tooltip box was hidden behind the 2nd chart. How to make it modal above all charts?

Answer (score 2):

You might be able to do it using a [React Portals](https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html) in a custom content renderer `<Tooltip content={renderTooltip} />`

Here is a basic example without portals: http://recharts.org/en-US/examples/CustomContentOfTooltip

Recharts issue to make this default here: https://github.com/recharts/recharts/issues/2458

Answer (score -1):

You might try using css to style the tooltip element's z-order so that it's above all the other elements in your document.